# SQLite database inside Phar archive

Tags: php, sqlite, phar

I'm trying to access SQLite database through PDO extension inside Phar archive, but I'm getting error:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file'

PHP manual says it's possible to modify files inside archive. How can I fix it?

Comment: SQLite needs random access on a database file, be able to grow it etc. Files in zip/phar archives can only be rewriten, not updated block-wise. No dice.

Comment: Isn't there any directive to set database read-only? In the fact, I only need read access.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I realized, that problem can be solved by a little hack.

1. Copy database file to system's temporary directory
2. Connect PDO to database copy and do your operations
3. Overwrite original database file with modified copy.

Not very reliable solution - you need to be careful about unhandled errors or exceptions, because you may lose your changes.